# Apply offset and limit to CQ5 jcr query

Tags: search, aem, jcr-sql2

I am using a simple SQL based jcr query which goes like :

```
select * from jcr:PageContent where cq:tags like '%tag1%' and cq:template like '%tremplate%'
```

This is working fine but now I need to add an offset and limit to implement pagination. I found examples for query builder but not for the basic SQL search.

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: I think you can use the setOffset(long offset) and setLimit(long limit) methods available in the Query object. Did you check that?

Comment: Oh so silly of me!!! :) many thanks.. it was in front of me all along !!